# Resize Image retrieved from s3 via intervention/image then re-upload back

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I want to do the resizing via queue. So I already uploaded the original image in s3 and it was successful.

However, when I tried to retrieve the image then resize it I ran into some problems.

This is my code:

```
$originalImage = base64_encode($banner->getImage('original'));
```

The code basically get the file from s3 and it is successful. I dump the results and I believe it is in some form of binary string.

Now here is the problem:

```
$resizedImage = Image::make($originalImage)->resize($dimensions[0], $dimensions[1]);
```

When dumped, the $resizedImage is empty string. I am clueless as to why and haven't seen any answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `base64` encode your image from `S3`. I believe you fail to load the image into intervention, but when you put it back onto `S3`, you can simply convert it to a string.

```
$resizedImage = Image::make($banner->getImage('original'))
    ->resize($dimensions[0], $dimensions[1]);

Storage::disk('s3')->put('/yourfolder/yourfile.jpg', (string) $resizedImage );
```

Comment: I will definitely try this, I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Did it help mate? :)